# MySql and C#: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been trying to connect to MySql Database and I keep having this error:

> ***SocketException: No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3306***

**C#**

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user=MyUsername;database=Mydatabase;port=3306;password=MyPassword;");
```

I tried to check if the problem is with my connection string but I tested more than 10 different formats and I keep getting this error.

what is weird is that I have a website and I use PHP to connect to the database and it works great without any errors.

**PHP**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MyDataBase");
```

Comment: In your PHP site, what is the port that you use to configure the SQL connection? Most likely the port is incorrect.

Comment: And what connection settings are you using with PHP?

Comment: I used the same port  (3306)

Comment: Either nobody is listening on port 3306 or 127.0.0.1 is not configured on machine or another application is already using the port 3306.  Also windows could be blocking a remote connection using a username and password.  So you may need to use a credential if the database is on a remote machine.

Comment: Actually the mysql connector would try to open a named pipe to open a connection and when that fails a tco connection, which also fails . I would check if the server is running or check the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following and seeing if it helps?

`TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;'`

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Option not supported.
Parameter name: trustservercertificate'

Comment: Interesting - admittedly, my question was for an SQL Server connection, I suppose it may not work for MySQL, but I know in the past, I had found it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because MySQL server was not running on Windows 11.

So to start the service go to => Services => MySQL80 and press "Start the service"

Also make sure the SSL connection is possible between the Server and Client.